# Use of is .... that .... if

Tags: grammar, british-english

What is the meaning of below sentence

> Life is a problem that will be hard if not impossible to solve.

Comment: What have you found out for yourself?

Comment: Problem is hard if we can solve
In this case, there is a solution.

The problem remains a problem if can not solve
In this case, there is no solution.

Comment: The 'if not impossible' is parenthetical.

Comment: so mean it's extraneous and don't add any additional meaning to the sentence?

Comment: No, it adds meaning. However, you can read it thus: "_Life is a problem that will be hard (if not impossible) to solve_". Does that help?

Comment: So can we distribute the meaning like this?

 
Life is a problem that will be hard to solve (if possible).


Life is a problem that will be impossible to solve (if not possible).

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: Thank you @marcellothearcane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can parse the meaning like this:

> Life is a problem that will be hard to solve (if possible). Life is a problem that will be impossible to solve (if not possible).
>
> [Kuldeep Bhimte](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/390443/kuldeep-bhimte), [in comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540078/use-of-is-that-if?noredirect=1#comment1323255_540078)